# Setting up Powemockito for static mocking

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit, powermock

I would like to make use of Powermock with Mockito to mock some static method calls.  I have followed instructions and examples from SO as well as the PowerMock [Getting Started](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/GettingStarted) and [MockStatic](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) pages as best I can, but I am yet to complete a mockStatic() call.

When I call mockStatic(foo.class) from my test class, I'm given the excception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/Mockito/mock/MockName
at org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic(PowerMockito.java:70)
at ...my test class method call...
```

I'm sure this is a setup problem, as I have been finding the terminology used for setting this up to be pretty confusing.  I did grab the Mockito Zip from the PowerMock [downloads](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/downloads/list).  In Eclipse (3.5.2) I opened the project properties and added all of the Jars to the build path.  I also tried adding the entire unzipped powermockito folder to my environment vars classpath, and then just the powermockito jar specifically when that didn't work out.

I have these annotationsat the class-level of my test class as well, per the powermock instructions:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ApplicationContextLoader.class)
```

Also these powermock-specific imports:

```
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
```

To those of you who have used PowerMockito before, even just a pointer in the right direction, or something to check would be really helpful.  I'm struggling to see how my setup differs from that of posts I have seen using - from what I can tell - the same syntax.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Not that I remember, although it's been a couple years.  I have the answer from @Walls upvoted, so that must have been the most help, short of a solution.

Answer (score 32):

Probably, the versions of Powermock and Mockito are not compatible. Fix that and it won't be a n issue anymore.

```
Mockito                     PowerMock
1.10.8+                     1.6.2+
1.9.5-rc1 - 1.9.5           1.5.0 - 1.5.6
1.9.0-rc1 & 1.9.0           1.4.10 - 1.4.12
1.8.5                       1.3.9 to 1.4.9
1.8.4                       1.3.7 & 1.3.8 
1.8.3                       1.3.6
1.8.1 & 1.8.2               1.3.5
1.8                         1.3
1.7                         1.2.5
```

See: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions

Comment: I found this link to have updated versions: https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions

Comment: Well, this solved my issue. I had been trying with Mockito 1.8.5 but with a higher PowerMock version. Reducing the PowerMock version to 1.4.9 solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a static mock object, in your `PrepareForTest` annotation, add the class that is USING the static object in addition to the static class itself.  If the class you are testing needs to use this static, add the current class to the annotation.  You don't actually mock the class, but it needs to be in the annotation for the static to hook in.  It sounds weird, but it works.

When adding multiple classes into the annotation you can have them inside `{}` and seperated by commas.  For example if your static class is `StaticA.class` and the class using the static is `CallerOfStatic.class` you can use:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({StaticA.class, CallerOfStatic.class})
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that out, making my annotations look like this:   `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)  @PrepareForTest( { ApplicationContextLoader.class,
  TestClass.class })
public class TestClass { ..test class code... }`

Comment: Haha, apparently I was too busy trying to make that readable to say that part.  But no it doesn't appear to be making any difference.

Comment: I don't see any indication that it's causing a problem, but are you sure it's supposed to be like that?  It doesn't look that way in the [MockStatic](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic) documentation

Comment: All our tests were having similar issues and I've had to up our code coverage a bunch with heavy use of singleton static classes and `getInstance()` style functions.  It haunted me for weeks, but it seemed to work.  You are not actually mocking the class you add that calls the static, you are giving a runtime hook so it knows when the static is called from this class, we will use a mock object instead of the normal static call.

Comment: @Ubunfu if it worked for you make sure to accept the answer so if people in the future run into a similar issue they know what worked without having to sift through the comments :)

Comment: Didn't help here either.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure powermockito and mockito versions aligned as in this chart - https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#supported-versions,

Easy way to find is,

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep mockito
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.9.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.5.6:compile
```

In my case, powermock `1.5.6` and mockito `1.9.5` were aligned but had to change to use `mockito 1.8.5`, as someone else in the dependency was already using mockito 1.8.5.

Following combination perfectly works for me,

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep mockito
[INFO] |  \- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-all:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.4.9:compile
```