# How to mock Spring Boot Session and SecurityContext for testing purpose

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

It is Spring Boot project. It uses SecurityContext.

Most of its Rest controller and service, depend on the role of its logged in user, for validation purpose. So during testing, I need a user to login.

Please inform me unit testing code example, for Spring boot, that involve login user process.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SecurityContextHolder.class,AuthenticationManager.class,UserRepository.class,UserCreationRequestRepository.class,        PasswordEncoder.class,AuthorityRepository.class,CacheManager.class,POMasterCompanyRepository.class,BranchRepository.class})
public class BOAuthControllerTest {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@Mock
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@Mock
private UserRepository userRepository;
@Mock
private UserCreationRequestRepository userCreationRequestRepository;
@Mock
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
@Mock
private AuthorityRepository authorityRepository;
@Mock
private CacheManager cacheManager;
@Mock
private POMasterCompanyRepository poMasterCompanyRepository;
@Mock
private BranchRepository branchRepository;
private UserService userService;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {

    userService = new UserService(userRepository, passwordEncoder, authorityRepository, cacheManager, userCreationRequestRepository,
            poMasterCompanyRepository,branchRepository);

    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("admin","admin");
    Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    SecurityContext securityContext = new SecurityContextImpl();
    securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);

            System.out.println(authenticationToken==null?"null":"not null");
    System.out.println(authenticationManager==null?"null":"not null");
    System.out.println(authentication==null?"null":"not null");
    System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()==null?"null":"not null");
    System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()==null?"null":"not null");
    System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName());
    System.out.println(securityContext.getAuthentication().getName());

    PowerMockito.mockStatic(SecurityContextHolder.class);
    when(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()).thenReturn(securityContext);

    System.out.println(userService.getUserWithAuthorities().isPresent());
}

@Test
public void loginAvailableForAll() throws Exception {

    System.out.println(userService.getUserWithAuthorities().isPresent());

}
```

}

Comment: Have you taken the time to read the [testing chapter of Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/test.html#test) which explains exactly how to do this. If that doesn't work, you are probably writing integration tests and then you will need to program the login (call the URL or send basic auth headers or... whatever authentication mechanism you choose to use).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerMock to mock `SecurityContextHolder`.
Example mocking `SecurityContex`t to return a list of desired roles

```java
    import org.junit.Test
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith
    import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito
    import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
    import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
    import org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken
    import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
    import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl

    import static org.mockito.Mockito.when

    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    @PrepareForTest([SecurityContextHolder.class])
    class Dummy {

    @Test
    void isAdminUser(){
        String roleList = 'ROLE_ADMIN'
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(SecurityContextHolder)
        when(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()).thenReturn(getDesiredSecurityContext(roleList))
        //assertTrue()
    }

    // This will create a security context with the list of roles required
    private SecurityContext getDesiredSecurityContext(String roles){
        List<String> roleList = roles.split(',')
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = roleList.collect { new SimpleGrantedAuthority(it)}
        SecurityContext securityContext = new SecurityContextImpl()
        securityContext.setAuthentication(new TestingAuthenticationToken(null,null,authorities))
        return securityContext
    }

  }
```

Comment: I tried, and attached my code above, but it doesn't work, keep giving me ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations$Mock ... please inform me, which part is wrong with my code

Comment: This might be due to version incompatibility between mockito and powermock. Check this link for the version compatibility - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19055650/setting-up-powemockito-for-static-mocking

Comment: okay, it works now, but this part "Authentication authentication = this.authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);" ... authentication is always null, it looks like it cannot authenticate, hmm, how to make it authenticate

Comment: I had actually mocked the Authentication object itself - securityContext.setAuthentication(new TestingAuthenticationToken(null,null,authorities))

Answer (score 6):

Instead of going for `PowerMock` set the context by your self.

As it was static method you can make that `SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext)` call in your `@Before` method.

**Example:**

```
 @Before
 void initContext(){
        SecurityContext securityContext = new SecurityContextImpl();
        securityContext.setAuthentication(new TestingAuthenticationToken(null,null,authorities));
        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
 }
```

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work, after setting the context, I tried to get the logged in user, but it doesn't exist